# Is there a way to have an item in an SWT List show multiple lines?

Tags: java, swt

I looked around but didn't find any examples of how this could be done with SWT. I'm looking for something like this:

[image: Mac Mail Sidebar]

I know each item can span multiple lines, but each line here has its own font and style. Is this possible with SWT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could achieve something similar using `StyledCellLabelProvider (thou probably not as fancy as in your example), please see [following code snippet](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFaceSnippets#Snippet049StyledCellLabelProvider) on how to do so.

There is [another example](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/JFaceSnippets#Snippet006TableMultiLineCells), which demonstrates, how to get multi line cells appearance.